# Started getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCapabilities' of undefined

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine, protractor

My tests were running fine but when `browser.getCapabilities();` is called in `OnComplete` method, it's throwing an error.

```
    //HTMLReport called once tests are finished
  onComplete: function () {
    var browserName, browserVersion;
    browser.getCapabilities();
    capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
      browserName = caps.get('browserName');
      browserVersion = caps.get('version');
      platform = caps.get('platform');
      var HTMLReport = require('protractor-html-reporter-2');
      testConfig = {
        reportTitle: 'Protractor Test Execution Report',
        outputPath: './reports',
        outputFilename: 'ProtractorTestReport',
        screenshotPath: '..//screenshots',
        testBrowser: browserName,
        browserVersion: browserVersion,
        modifiedSuiteName: false,
        screenshotsOnlyOnFailure: true,
        testPlatform: platform
      };
      new HTMLReport().from('xmlresults.xml', testConfig);
    });
```

Console:

```
E/launcher - Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCapabilities' of undefined
    at onComplete (/Users/Testbook/Documents/protractorproj/conf/conf.js:63:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/frameworks/jasmine.js:115:27
    at module.exports.jasmineDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/lib/reporters/completion_reporter.js:15:5)
    at dispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:4366:28)
    at ReportDispatcher.jasmineDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:4337:11)
    at QueueRunner.onComplete (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:994:18)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:4231:12)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
```

Comment: Is browser undefined prior to this method?

Answer (score 0):

Below piece of code on the top of my conf.js file was the culprit. Not sure how it got added there since I didn't add it.

```
const { browser } = require('protractor');
```